# Select identical rows based on max values of a column and only choose one of rows when max equals

Tags: mysql, group-by, max, self-join

I have a table named 'demo' with the following data:

```
Name    Group   MX
A        XY     1
B        YZ     1
B        XY     2
C        YZ     5
C        XY     3
D        YZ     2
E        YZ     1
E        XY     1
```

I want unique names based on 'MX' maximum value, when the 'MX' for two identical names are equal I need one of them as illustrated below:

```
Name    Group   MX
A        XY     1
B        XY     2
C        YZ     5
D        YZ     2
E        YZ     1   -- or this {E   XY   1}
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT demo.Name, demo.Group, demo.MX
    FROM ( 
        SELECT Name, MAX(MX) AS max_values 
        FROM demo
        GROUP BY Name
     ) demo2
INNER JOIN demo
ON demo.Name = demo2.Name
AND demo.MX = demo2.max_values
```

It is working charmingly, but when the two names are identical it displays both as follow:

```
Name    Group   MX
A        XY      1
B        XY      2
C        YZ      5
D        YZ      2
E        YZ      1 
E        XY      1
```

What methods do you recommend?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for avoid two value where  Name and MX are equals  you could use a (fake) aggregation function  and group by eg:

```
SELECT demo.Name, min(demo.Group), demo.MX
    FROM ( 
        SELECT Name, MAX(MX) AS max_values 
        FROM demo
        GROUP BY Name
     ) demo2
INNER JOIN demo ON demo.Name = demo2.Name AND demo.MX = demo2.max_values
GROUP BY demo.Name, demo.MX
```